# Unable to install GPU enabled TensorFlow

Tags: tensorflow, gpu

To install TensorFlow with GPU on an Ubuntu system, I installed CUDA v 8.0 using "cuda-repo-ubuntu1404_8.0.44-1_amd64.deb" and cuDNN using "cudnn-8.0-linux-x64-v5.1", however, on uncompressing the file and copying them into CUDA toolkit the following files are added to the /usr/local/cuda/lib64 folder:

```
libcudnn.so  
libcudnn.so.5  
libcudnn.so.5.1.5  
libcudnn_static.a
```

The following are the environment variables in ~/.profile file

```
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/cuda/lib64
CUDA_PATH=/usr/local/cuda
```

On running the ./configure command inside the tensorflow folder the following error is displayed:

```
ubuntu@ip-172-31-20-185:~/tensorflow$ ./configure
Please specify the location of python. [Default is /usr/bin/python]:
Do you wish to build TensorFlow with Google Cloud Platform support? [y/N] n
No Google Cloud Platform support will be enabled for TensorFlow
Do you wish to build TensorFlow with GPU support? [y/N] y
GPU support will be enabled for TensorFlow
Please specify which gcc nvcc should use as the host compiler. [Default is /usr/bin/gcc]:
Please specify the Cuda SDK version you want to use, e.g. 7.0. [Leave empty to use system default]: 8.0
Please specify the location where CUDA 8.0 toolkit is installed. Refer to README.md for more details. [Default is /usr/local/cuda]:
Invalid path to CUDA 8.0 toolkit. /usr/local/cuda/lib64/libcudart.so.8.0 cannot be found
```

Am I missing any steps? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You may be missing the package. Try `apt-get install cuda-cudart-7-0`.

Comment: On running the command `apt-get install cuda-cudart-8-0` it states `cuda-cudart-8-0 is already the newest version.` and the libcudart package is not added to cuda/lib64

Comment: Oh good, what does `dpkg -S libcudart.so.8` say?

Comment: `ubuntu@ip-172-31-20-185:/usr/local/cuda/lib64$ dpkg -S libcudart.so.8
cuda-cudart-8-0: /usr/local/cuda-8.0/targets/x86_64-linux/lib/libcudart.so.8.0.44
cuda-cudart-8-0: /usr/local/cuda-8.0/targets/x86_64-linux/lib/libcudart.so.8.0
ubuntu@ip-172-31-20-185:/usr/local/cuda/lib64$ cd /usr/local/ `

Comment: Maybe they changed the install paths. You probably want to `ln -s /usr/local/cuda-8.0/targets/x86_64-linux/lib/* /usr/local/cuda/lib64` as root.

Comment: There is no folder named "cuda-8.0" in the /usr/local folder

Comment: Maybe `sudo apt-get install --reinstall cuda-cudard-8-0`?

Comment: While doing so, the following error is encountered `dpkg: error processing archive /var/cuda-repo-8-0-local/./cuda-cudart-8-0_8.0.44-1_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 trying to overwrite '/usr/local/cuda-8.0/lib64', which is also in package cuda-driver-dev-8-0 8.0.44-1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cuda-repo-8-0-local/./cuda-cudart-8-0_8.0.44-1_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)`

Comment: It looks like you might be able to `dpkg -i --force-overwrite /var/cuda-repo-8-0-local/./cuda-cudart-8-0_8.0.44-1_amd64.de‌​b` then `apt-get install -f`. I am not sure why those packages have duplicate files.

Comment: It shows an error `dpkg: error processing archive /var/cuda-repo-8-0-local/./cuda-cudart-8-0_8.0.44-1_amd64.de‌​‌​b (--install):
 cannot access archive: No such file or directory`

Comment: How about `apt-get -o Dpkg::Options::="--force-overwrite" install --reinstall cuda-cudart-8-0`?

Comment: Using the above command, the `libcudart.so.8.0` is now present in the `/usr/local/cuda/lib64`, hwoever on running the ./configure command to set up tensorflow, it shows an error stating `Cuda toolkit is missing`

Comment: OK, it looks like this is not going to be simple. Since this is a build/install problem, could you create an issue on our [github issues](https://www.github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues) and include a link here? Mention @drpngx in our post. Thanks.

Comment: Sure, I appreciate your assistance. This is the link to the GitHub issue https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/5554

Answer (score 0):

This might be because of multiple versions of CUDA installed in your system.
Remove all the CUDA versions using `sudo apt-get purge cuda-.`
Install the CUDA 8.0.

Download the CUDA toolkit from this [link](https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-downloads?target_os=Linux). Install local deb file.

After that Run

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install cuda
```